# How to root a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo bought in China?

Tags: samsung, rooting

I bought a brand new Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Neo here in China, just to find out that all the major Google apps are obviously not working.

I found some comments in this forum that gave me hope, apparently you just need to root it and install something, and then it works out like a phone bought in Europe.

Could anyone give me some detailed and simple advice on how to do that? I'm not experienced at all with this and I'm afraid to damage my phone entirely if I intervene there through rooting.

Comment: Try using this guide over the [PrimeHowTo](https://web.archive.org/web/20170930063914/http://primehowto.com/root-galaxy-note-3-neo-sm-n7506v/) which I think is going to help you in getting things step-by-step. Nothing much is changed over here I guess, things are mostly the same and for self-satisfaction, I would say you can work with this one.

Answer (score 0):

**There are many clones that originate from the east like China.** Meaning, things like CF-ROOT are made for that particular model and not a clone.

The `build.prop` could have been modified to state those things, most likely if it has a MediaTek processor - it's a clone.

If you are sure it's not a clone, root the phone, google TWRP and download their custom recovery for your device (as a tar file) then use Odin to flash the tar (AP). Then go to XDA Developers and flash any ROM from the recovery and it acts like a European device.

Comment: If it is a clone, do not flash a ROM for the Note 3 Neo. It will likely softbrick the phone. If it's a clone, it will not have the same hardware that the real model will have and the ROM will not work.